# background image not working right

Tags: image, tkinter, label

my goal: have a background image which occupies the full window of the display. And then on it, place image buttons which will be nicely centered on this window (buttons being arranged in grid).
The image is 1920X1080. 
I have other code snippet which follows exactly the same sequence and the image appears in background. So totally baffled. But wanted to understand the logic correctly of this code/instead of relying on luck!..Note that on the other working code, I do both a place and grid of the background_label !. With this code the buttons don't appear at all.
when I use background_label(content....), the image does appear in the background with buttons in front, but in that case the whole display window is not occupied. The image just expands to fill the area occupied by button images.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))
print(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())
#prints as 1920 & 1080

#old background_image_file='waves1600x926.gif'

background_image_file='Lake.gif' #this is 1080X1920
background_image=PhotoImage(file=background_image_file)
background_label =ttk.Label(root,image=background_image) #tried content instead of root also
background_label.place(x=0, y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1)
background_label.grid()

logos=['abc','cbs','nbc','fox','cnbc','amc','bet']
logobuttons=defaultdict(str)
logoimgs=defaultdict(str)
for logo in logos:

    logoimgs[logo]=PhotoImage(file=LOGODIR+logo+'.gif')

    logobuttons[logo]=ttk.Button(content,image=logoimgs[logo])


content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W))

col=0
row=0
maxcols=5
for logo in logos:
    logobuttons[logo].grid(row=row,column=col,pady=5,padx=5)
    if col == maxcols:
        col=0
        row=row+1
    else:
        col=col+1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question? Just a general "why is this not working"?

Comment: My question:  what should I change to make it display the buttons on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you use both `place` and `grid`, only the last one you call for a given widget has any effect. Thus, when you call `background_label.grid()` it totally negates the effect of `background_label.place(...)`. In other words, you need to remove the call to `grid` for this widget.

If you want a background image, the best solution is to use place with a relative width and height of 1. You should also create the widget that contains the image first, so it is lowest in the stacking order. Though, you can always lower it later.

Comment: I have: background_label.place(x=0, y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Comment: I do have it as you say: background_label.place(x=0, y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1) above. The label is also getting created before others (I have content created before it, but that is because I had tried with background label created with content frame as parent). My question: is what should I change to make it  display the buttons on top of the image. Thnks

Comment: Your background needs to be the first widget you create. Widgets are created in a stack. As your code is now, the label is above `content`, so anything in `content` will be below the label